# MYSQL JSON - how do I access nested JSON object that's indexed by numerical key?

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysql-8.0, document-store

I am trying to extract JSON document subtree that's indexed by numerical key.

My JSON string:

```
{
    "pk": 20,
    "tree": {
        "100": {
            "values": [
                1, 2, 3
            ]
        },
        "abc" => 999
    }
}
```

My code:

```php
$session = mysql_xdevapi\getSession("mysqlx://root:letmein@localhost");
$schema = $session->getSchema('test');
$coll = $schema->getCollection('myColl');
$expr = mysql_xdevapi\Expression('$.tree.*');
$result = $coll->find('$.pk=20')->fields(['$.tree[100]'])->execute();
```

Using `'$.tree[100]'` results in

```
    [
        'tree' => null
    ]
```

Using `'$.tree.*'` results in

```
    [
        'tree' => [
            0 => [
                1, 2, 3
            ],
            1 => 999
        ]
    ]
```

Using `'$.tree.abc'` results in

```
    [
        'tree' => [
            'abc' => 999
        ]
    ]
```

So, `'$.tree.abc'` works, but `'$.tree[100]'` doesnt.

**Question**. How can I access `values` key using '$.tree[100]' expression?

Thanks!

Comment: Try: `... $coll->find('$.pk=20')->fields(['$.tree."100"'])->execute();`.

Comment: nope: mysql_xdevapi\CollectionFind::fields(): Error while parsing, details: CDK Error: After seeing '$.tree."100" AS ', looking at '100': Expected identifier after AS (cdk:8). How would you do that search from Javascript mysqlsh?

Comment: Filed a bug report: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=78331.

Comment: This works for me from mysqlsh-js: `mysqlsh-js> db.myColl.find("pk = 20").fields("tree.'100'");`.

Comment: Yes, it does. But only from mysqlsh. There's a bug in PHP extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thnx for report, following case:

> ```
> $expr = mysql_xdevapi\Expression('$.tree."100"'); 
> $result = $coll->find('$.pk=25')->fields($expr)->execute();
> ```

will be supported in mysql_xdevapi v8.0.18 which is planned for Oct 14.